# Storing two separate image in two separate cell in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different field in my form to collect image from user and store it in two different cell in MySQL table. The following program giving me this error. Note that my count[$images] shows me result = 1

036fb3018f.jpg
**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in  on line 43

```
<input type="file" id="topImg" name="topImg">   
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="featuredImg">

$images = [];
foreach(['featuredImg','topImg'] AS $field){
$permitted  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
$file_name  = $file[$field]['name'];
$file_size  = $file[$field]['size'];
$file_temp  = $file[$field]['tmp_name'];
    $div             = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext        = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_image    = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
    $images[] =  $unique_image;

    echo $images[0];
    echo $images[1]; // Line 43

        $images[]  = "../images/uploads/".$unique_image;
}
```

Comment: So.. total count of `$images` array is 1 (having one value), then how it display the second value in an array ??

Comment: No, Not as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You must move your echo outside the for loop. 
When it goes for the first iteration, the index 1 will not be found.

Also you have assigned two values to your array for each loop.

```
<input type="file" id="topImg" name="topImg">   
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="featuredImg">

$images = [];
foreach(['featuredImg','topImg'] AS $field){
    $permitted  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $file_name  = $file[$field]['name'];
    $file_size  = $file[$field]['size'];
    $file_temp  = $file[$field]['tmp_name'];
    $div             = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext        = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_image    = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;

    $images[] =  "../images/uploads/".$unique_image;

}

echo $images[0];
echo $images[1];
```